# Why is using a variable in a for loop faster than some function output?

Tags: php, optimization

On [Symfony blog](http://www.symfony-project.org/blog//2007/06/11/is-symfony-too-slow-for-real-world-usage), in support of Symfony being faster, it was mentioned that

```
for ($i = 0; $i<count($my_array); $i++)
```

is slower as compared to

```
for ($i = 0, $count = count($my_array); $i<$count; $i++)
```

The reason they had mentioned was "Because we measured". But what exactly is the reason for the latter being faster out of the two approaches mentioned above ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first 'for' calculates count of $my_array every iterate. The second 'for' calculates count once.

Comment: Now, that you have answered, it looks pretty obvious and I feel like an idiot to have asked this question in the very first place. Thanks a lot !:)